# Which of these generated deb from kernel compilation I need to install?

Tags: package-management, kernel, compiling

My compiled kernel generated the following:

```
linux-cloud-tools-4.15.0-23_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-cloud-tools-4.15.0-23-dbgsym_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.ddeb
linux-cloud-tools-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-headers-4.15.0-23_4.15.0-23.25_all.deb
linux-headers-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-modules-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-tools-4.15.0-23_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
linux-tools-4.15.0-23-dbgsym_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.ddeb
linux-tools-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb
```

I'm used to the linux headers, linux image and linux extra, but in this one there's no extra, only `linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-23-generic_4.15.0-23.25_amd64.deb`.

Which os these I need to install to update my kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok Linux- image is the core kernel.
Linux-modules and Linux-modules-extra are the kernel modules. You may need one or both depending on the hardware drivers needed, and how much you built into the kernel.
If you plan on building kernel modules, then you need both header packages.
The tool packages are for manipulating kernel settings I believe.